# Dragon with storm call

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Whenever I use Storm Call, a black and white dragon comes with it every time. It is not hostile words me but it lasts as long as the shout does. It doesn’t show a name and I can’t interact with him. Is this normal? I use all three words if that helps. Looking it up doesn’t mention it at all.

Comment: Are you using any mods?

Comment: No, I am not using any mods.

Comment: It doesn’t actually happen every time, only out in the open, not in any cities.

Comment: Without mods this does not seem plausible. Is it possible for you to post a screen shot?

Comment: I will try but it wont be good quality coz it is on my pa4